# Finding days between two dates in laravel

Tags: php, php-carbon

I have to dates. Now, I need to find the difference between these two for further calculations.

I tried different ways but I am not able to fix the issues. Can anyone tell me the best way to do it.

My code is:

```
public function leaveRequest(request $request)
{
    $fdate=$request->Fdate;
    $tdate=$request->Tdate;

    $start = Carbon::parse($fdate)->format('Y/m/d');
    $end =  Carbon::parse($tdate)->format('Y/m/d');

    $days = $end->diffInDays($start);
    /*$days=date_diff($end,$start);*/
    echo $days;
    exit;

    $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
    Mail::send('pages.leave', ['user' => $request,'userId'=>$user], function ($m) use ($request) {
        $m->to($request->Email)->subject('Leave Request!');
    });

    DB::table('leaves')->insert(
        ['user' => Auth::user()->id, 'request_date' => Carbon::now(),'start' => $start,'end' => $end,'permissions' => "Pending",'leave_status' => "Active"]
    );

    return redirect()->back()->with('message','Your request has sent');
}
```

If I can get the days then I can insert it into the leaves table.

Comment: The actual answer to this question is to do just `$start = Carbon::parse($fdate);` and `$end =  Carbon::parse($tdate);` By using the `Carbon::format()` function you got a string, so you would have received an error like "Call to member function diffInDays() on non-object"

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You don't need Carbon, you can do that using simple PHP. Best is to use PHP OOP way. Like this:

```
$fdate = $request->Fdate;
$tdate = $request->Tdate;
$datetime1 = new DateTime($fdate);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($tdate);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$days = $interval->format('%a');//now do whatever you like with $days
```

PS : DateTime is not a function, it's a class, so don't forget to add : `use DateTime;` at top of your controller so that it can reference to right root class, or use `\DateTime()` instead when making its instance.

Comment: I am writing this code in a Controller. This code throws an error : Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DateTime' not found. DateTime works with php.

Comment: Add `use DateTime;` at the top of the controller and try again.

Comment: Tried that and it worked!. Before, I was using DateTime of Carbon. It didn't helped me. Thanks

Comment: @Kiran Rai Chamling, Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you to close this thread. Thanks

Comment: Just in case something went wrong, you can add `try { } catch (\Exception $e){}` on your `DateTime` code. Because `DateTime` class would throw `Exception` when error occured. Thanks to PHPStorm for reminds me.

Comment: This worked for me $datetime1->diff($datetime2)->days

Answer (score 21):

```
$to = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', '2015-5-5 3:30:34');
$from = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', '2015-5-6 9:30:34');

$diff_in_days = $to->diffInDays($from);

print_r($diff_in_days); // Output: 1
```

Answer (score 9):

Why not use Carbon helper to get the exact date

```
$to = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->to);
$from = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->from);

        $years = $to->diffInYears($from);
        $months = $to->diffInMonths($from);
        $weeks = $to->diffInWeeks($from);
        $days = $to->diffInDays($from);
        $hours = $to->diffInHours($from);
        $minutes = $to->diffInMinutes($from);
        $seconds = $to->diffInSeconds($from);
```

Answer (score 4):

Anyone using PHP version < php 5.3, they can do using timestamps,
Like this:

```
$fdate = $request->Fdate;
$tdate = $request->Tdate;
$datetime1 = strtotime($fdate); // convert to timestamps
$datetime2 = strtotime($tdate); // convert to timestamps
$days = (int)(($datetime2 - $datetime1)/86400); // will give the difference in days , 86400 is the timestamp difference of a day
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$from=Carbon::now()->subDays(5)->toDateString();

$current=Carbon::now()->toDateString();

$peoples= People::whereBetween('joiningdate',array($diff,$current))->get();
```

Comment: You need to provide an explanation why your answer addresses the original question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
// get from and throung date
$from_date = Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2022-03-10'))); 
$through_date = Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2022-03-12'))); 
    
// get total number of minutes between from and throung date
$shift_difference = $from_date->diffInDays($through_date);

// will output $shift_difference = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this method and it is properly working for me. If you want to verify date of birth with the requested age then use it.

```
$date_of_birth = Carbon::parse($request->input('student_dob'));
$current_date = Carbon::now();

if ($current_date->diffInYears($date_of_birth) != $request->input('student_age')) {
    return response(['status' => false, 'error' => [
        'student_dob' => ['date of birth not matched with age']
    ]], 500);
}
```