# How to found settlement amount between two dates in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

How to calculate the amount between 2 dates.
For example
Consider if in month January 2021
I need to get the amount between From Date: `1st Jan 2021` and To Date : `15 Jan 2021.
The calculation should be = Total Amount - (Amount from 16 Jan to 31 Jan)

Hope for a guidance to solve this :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508963/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-using-carbon-and-blade take a look this

Comment: I assume that you will calculate amount from the database, then you should use whereBetween https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Use `whereBetween`... Try:

```
$date1 = date('2021-01-01');
$date2 = date('2021-01-15');
    
Your_Model::whereBetween('date_col', [$date1, $date2])
    ->select( DB::raw('SUM(your_col) as amount'))
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = 1st Jan 2021 //formate upto you, standard format 2021-01-01
$date2 = 15 Jan 2021 //formate upto you, standard format 2021-01-15

$total_amount = $date1->diff($date2);
```

Or follow this,

[Finding days between two dates in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443987/finding-days-between-two-dates-in-laravel/41444467)

I hope it will be work!